# Solr Move Cores to another server

Tags: solr

While doing a sitecore 9.1 install  we installed solr as a part of the CM server. We now want to move SOLR to its own separate server. This is what i did 
I did a clean install of solr in the new server and moved all the cores files under

> solr/server/solr (sitecore_core_index, sitecore_master_index)

etc to the new server. 
In the connection string i repointed the solr to the new server. 
But for some reason when i do 
https://mySolr:8983/solr and try to look at cores i dont find any of those.

Is there any thing else i should be doing or doing things differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to delete all the data folders within each core folder  then restart Solr service, Then try accessing the Solr admin again and verify that Cores are showing up.
You would need to rebuild the indexes from Sitecore control panel again

Comment: This did it. deleting the data folder and restarting services fixed the solr part of it.  But i am not able to rebuild the indexes. throws error.

Comment: @NightMonger make sure the names of the Solr cores matches what is in your Sitecore configurations, you may need to check your crawling log files to see the error

Comment: I got it working finally. i fixed this by doing "Populate solr managed Schema " first and then rebuilding the index.

Answer (score 0):

Seems solr is not moved properly.Try doing this way:

Take backup of SOLR from CM using below command.

[http://localhost:8983/solr/your-collection-name/replication?command=backup&location=d:\my-solr-backup](http://localhost:8983/solr/your-collection-name/replication?command=backup&location=d:%5Cmy-solr-backup)

And restore on new server using below command.

[http://localhost:8983/solr/your-collection-name/replication?command=restore&location=d:\my-solr-backup](http://localhost:8983/solr/your-collection-name/replication?command=restore&location=d:%5Cmy-solr-backup)